# How do I include tables with Ascii art lines in my answer?

Tags: discussion, faq

Some answers on the site like [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27932/1396) and [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27319/1396) include tables drawn with ascii art. Is this done by hand or is there a tool I can use to help me?

Comment: why don't we just allow HTML tables? I don't understand everyone's hatred of HTML tables.. with HTML tables, you can easily right click export to Excel.

Comment: @AaronKempf I'd prefer [markdown tables](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#table) myself

Answer (score 32):

If you have tab-delimited text you can use [this web site tool](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) to convert it into a table, either in 'MySQL' or 'Unicode Art' style, eg:

```
+-------+-------+
| LEVEL | DUMMY |
+-------+-------+
|     1 | X     |
|     2 | X     |
|     3 | X     |
+-------+-------+

╔═══════╦═══════╗
║ LEVEL ║ DUMMY ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║     1 ║ X     ║
║     2 ║ X     ║
║     3 ║ X     ║
╚═══════╩═══════╝
```

Screen grab of site:

[image: Screen grab of site]

It was created by another Stack Exchange user [Senseful](http://stackexchange.com/users/16422/senseful).

If your table just fails to fit without scrollbars, you may want to make the text smaller by using `<pre><sub></sub></pre>` rather than indentation for the code block:

```
╔══════════╦═════════════════╦══════════════════════╦═════════════╦════════════════════════════════╗
║ index_id ║ index_type_desc ║ alloc_unit_type_desc ║ index_level ║ avg_page_space_used_in_percent ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║        1 ║ CLUSTERED INDEX ║ IN_ROW_DATA          ║           0 ║ 50.3953545836422               ║
║        1 ║ CLUSTERED INDEX ║ ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA    ║           0 ║ 74.3019520632567               ║
║        1 ║ CLUSTERED INDEX ║ LOB_DATA             ║           0 ║ 99.0239683716333               ║
╚══════════╩═════════════════╩══════════════════════╩═════════════╩════════════════════════════════╝
```

You can even take it further but `<sub>` [isn't really a substitute for `<small>`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40035/allow-the-small-tag) and the vertical spacing is perhaps getting annoying by this stage (it's also getting a little hard to read):

```
╔══════════╦═════════════════╦══════════════════════╦═════════════╦════════════════════════════════╗
║ index_id ║ index_type_desc ║ alloc_unit_type_desc ║ index_level ║ avg_page_space_used_in_percent ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║        1 ║ CLUSTERED INDEX ║ IN_ROW_DATA          ║           0 ║ 50.3953545836422               ║
║        1 ║ CLUSTERED INDEX ║ ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA    ║           0 ║ 74.3019520632567               ║
║        1 ║ CLUSTERED INDEX ║ LOB_DATA             ║           0 ║ 99.0239683716333               ║
╚══════════╩═════════════════╩══════════════════════╩═════════════╩════════════════════════════════╝
```

Perhaps not so bad with 'MySQL' style:

```
+-------+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| LEVEL | DUMMY | DUMMY_1 | DUMMY_2 | DUMMY_3 | DUMMY_4 | DUMMY_5 | DUMMY_6 | DUMMY_7 | DUMMY_8 | DUMMY_9 | DUMMY_10 | DUMMY_11 | DUMMY_12 |
+-------+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|     1 | X     | X       | X       | X       | X       | X       | X       | X       | X       | X       | X        | X        | X        |
|     2 | X     | X       | X       | X       | X       | X       | X       | X       | X       | X       | X        | X        | X        |
|     3 | X     | X       | X       | X       | X       | X       | X       | X       | X       | X       | X        | X        | X        |
+-------+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Finally, if you are using SQLFiddle, choose 'Markdown' from the 'Run SQL' dropdown and [you get something like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/3651):

```
[SQL Fiddle][1]

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:



**Query 1**:

    select level, dummy from dual connect by level<4

**[Results][2]**:

    | LEVEL | DUMMY |
    -----------------
    |     1 |     X |
    |     2 |     X |
    |     3 |     X |



  [1]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/3652

  [2]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/3652/0
```

which looks like this if you paste it straight into an answer:

---

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/3652)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
select level, dummy from dual connect by level<4
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/3652/0)**:

```
| LEVEL | DUMMY |
-----------------
|     1 |     X |
|     2 |     X |
|     3 |     X |
```

---

Another useful tool for generating tables is available at https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ - just a simple copy-paste of the output from an SSMS query results grid will cause an ASCII table to be generated with headers.

Comment: I'd actually always wondered about this myself! :D

Comment: @Aarthi would a feature-request for [markdown tables](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#table) just for dba.se be rejected out of hand do you think? I'm aware there is one [on mSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566/166851) but we are dealing with tabular data in a higher proportion of answers

Answer (score 4):

## PostgreSQL

PostgreSQL's official client, `psql`, makes this task super easy. It's a command line client.

Further formatting options are available,

```
Formatting
  \a                     toggle between unaligned and aligned output mode
  \C [STRING]            set table title, or unset if none
  \f [STRING]            show or set field separator for unaligned query output
  \H                     toggle HTML output mode (currently off)
  \pset [NAME [VALUE]]   set table output option
                         (NAME := {format|border|expanded|fieldsep|fieldsep_zero|footer|null|
                         numericlocale|recordsep|recordsep_zero|tuples_only|title|tableattr|pager|
                         unicode_border_linestyle|unicode_column_linestyle|unicode_header_linestyle})
  \t [on|off]            show only rows (currently off)
  \T [STRING]            set HTML <table> tag attributes, or unset if none
  \x [on|off|auto]       toggle expanded output (currently off)
```

*in the below examples `TABLE myTable;` is merely a shorthand for `SELECT * FROM myTable;`*

So for instance, a quick display of `\pset border`

```
test=# \pset border
Border style is 1.  (this is the default)
test=# TABLE foobar;
 x |         y         
---+-------------------
 1 | -5.53865572996438
 2 | -7.67541305348277
 3 | 0.195378532633185
 4 |  3.72031048033386
 5 |  1.67127958964556
(5 rows)

test=# \pset border 0
Border style is 0.
test=# TABLE foobar;
x         y         
- -----------------
1 -5.53865572996438
2 -7.67541305348277
3 0.195378532633185
4  3.72031048033386
5  1.67127958964556
(5 rows)

test=# \pset border 2
Border style is 2.
test=# TABLE foobar;
+---+-------------------+
| x |         y         |
+---+-------------------+
| 1 | -5.53865572996438 |
| 2 | -7.67541305348277 |
| 3 | 0.195378532633185 |
| 4 |  3.72031048033386 |
| 5 |  1.67127958964556 |
+---+-------------------+
(5 rows)
```

Other unicode options are kind of cool too.

```
test=# \pset linestyle unicode
Line style is unicode.
test=# TABLE foobar;
┌───┬───────────────────┐
│ x │         y         │
├───┼───────────────────┤
│ 1 │ -5.53865572996438 │
│ 2 │ -7.67541305348277 │
│ 3 │ 0.195378532633185 │
│ 4 │  3.72031048033386 │
│ 5 │  1.67127958964556 │
└───┴───────────────────┘
(5 rows)


test=# \pset unicode_column_linestyle double
Unicode column line style is "double".
test=# \pset unicode_header_linestyle double
Unicode header line style is "double".
test=# \pset title 'My Foobar'
Title is "My Foobar".
test=# TABLE foobar;
        My Foobar
┌───╥───────────────────┐
│ x ║         y         │
╞═══╬═══════════════════╡
│ 1 ║ -5.53865572996438 │
│ 2 ║ -7.67541305348277 │
│ 3 ║ 0.195378532633185 │
│ 4 ║  3.72031048033386 │
│ 5 ║  1.67127958964556 │
└───╨───────────────────┘
(5 rows)
```

Some other notes

- `footer` is corresponds to `(5 rows)` in the above example
- The *expanded display* `\pset expanded on` abbreviated `\x` is something *entirely* different. I'm not sure who uses it, or why. It's a horrible display (imho).

Expanded display,

```
test=# TABLE foobar;
My Foobar
┌─[ RECORD 1 ]──────────┐
│ x ║ 1                 │
│ y ║ -5.53865572996438 │
╞═[ RECORD 2 ]══════════╡
│ x ║ 2                 │
│ y ║ -7.67541305348277 │
╞═[ RECORD 3 ]══════════╡
│ x ║ 3                 │
│ y ║ 0.195378532633185 │
╞═[ RECORD 4 ]══════════╡
│ x ║ 4                 │
│ y ║ 3.72031048033386  │
╞═[ RECORD 5 ]══════════╡
│ x ║ 5                 │
│ y ║ 1.67127958964556  │
└───╨───────────────────┘
```

Comment: expanded display is awesome for display a row (or a small number of rows) with lots of columns